# Receive numeric data from the Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I want to display a numerical value for a score in a TextView, but the application always closes.

This is my code

````
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());

        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String valuePoints = dataSnapshot.child("current_points").getValue(String.class);
                mTextViewPoints = findViewById(R.id.current_points);
                mTextViewPoints.setText(valuePoints);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                // Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }```

Other values that contain letters are numbers he displays, but when it comes only to numbers he closes.
Where am I going wrong?
````

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Vanderclin Rocha,

Initially, the TextView cannot be defined in callback ValueEventListener, you should be defined when the view gets started.

The issue in your code textView return null, you can do debugging and see it.
and this is the current way to get data and set it into TextView.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());
```

TextView mTextViewPoints  = findViewById(R.id.current_points);

```
    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String valuePoints = dataSnapshot.child("current_points").getValue(String.class);
            mTextViewPoints.setText(valuePoints);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            // Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

**I hope this helps you**